TailwindCSS Syntax Error: The `border-border` class does not exist when using ShadCN UI inside Turborepo
So I am trying to use ShadCN components in the ui package in my turborepo. I have setup tailwind successfully, then I followed the instructions given on ShadCN Manual Installation to setup shadcn ui in the package. Now when I try to build the ui package it gives me the following error:
Error:
> @e-commerce-platform/ui@0.0.0 build C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\packages\ui
> tailwindcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ./dist/index.css


Rebuilding...
CssSyntaxError: tailwindcss: C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\packages\ui\src\styles.css:1:1: The border-border class does not exist. If border-border is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive.
    at Input.error (C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\postcss@8.4.47\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:106:16)
    at AtRule.error (C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\postcss@8.4.47\node_modules\postcss\lib\node.js:115:32)
    at processApply (C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\tailwindcss@3.4.13\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\expandApplyAtRules.js:380:29)
    at C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\tailwindcss@3.4.13\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\expandApplyAtRules.js:551:9
    at C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\tailwindcss@3.4.13\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\processTailwindFeatures.js:55:50
    at async Object.Once (C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\tailwindcss@3.4.13\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\build\plugin.js:245:17)
    at async LazyResult.runAsync (C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\postcss@8.4.47\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:261:11)
    at async build (C:\Users\aayus\Projects\e-commerce-platform\node_modules\.pnpm\tailwindcss@3.4.13\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\build\index.js:49:9) {
  reason: 'The border-border class does not exist. If border-border is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive.',
  file: 'C:\\Users\\aayus\\Projects\\e-commerce-platform\\packages\\ui\\src\\styles.css',
  source: '@tailwind base;\r\n' +
    '@tailwind components;\r\n' +
    '@tailwind utilities;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '@layer base {\r\n' +
    '  :root {\r\n' +
    '    --background: 0 0% 100%;\r\n' +
    '    --foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --muted: 210 40% 96.1%;\r\n' +
    '    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 46.9%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --popover: 0 0% 100%;\r\n' +
    '    --popover-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --border: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;\r\n' +
    '    --input: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --card: 0 0% 100%;\r\n' +
    '    --card-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --primary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '    --primary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --secondary: 210 40% 96.1%;\r\n' +
    '    --secondary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --accent: 210 40% 96.1%;\r\n' +
    '    --accent-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --destructive: 0 100% 50%;\r\n' +
    '    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --ring: 215 20.2% 65.1%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --radius: 0.5rem;\r\n' +
    '  }\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '  .dark {\r\n' +
    '    --background: 224 71% 4%;\r\n' +
    '    --foreground: 213 31% 91%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --muted: 223 47% 11%;\r\n' +
    '    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 56.9%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --accent: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
    '    --accent-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --popover: 224 71% 4%;\r\n' +
    '    --popover-foreground: 215 20.2% 65.1%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --border: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
    '    --input: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --card: 224 71% 4%;\r\n' +
    '    --card-foreground: 213 31% 91%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --primary: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
    '    --primary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 1.2%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --secondary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
    '    --secondary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --destructive: 0 63% 31%;\r\n' +
    '    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --ring: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '    --radius: 0.5rem;\r\n' +
    '  }\r\n' +
    '}\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    '@layer base {\r\n' +
    '  * {\r\n' +
    '    @apply border-border;\r\n' +
    '  }\r\n' +
    '  body {\r\n' +
    '    @apply bg-background text-foreground;\r\n' +
    '    font-feature-settings:\r\n' +
    '      "rlig" 1,\r\n' +
    '      "calt" 1;\r\n' +
    '  }\r\n' +
    '}\r\n',
  line: 1,
  column: 1,
  endLine: 1,
  endColumn: 16,
  input: {
    column: 1,
    endColumn: 16,
    endLine: 1,
    line: 1,
    source: '@tailwind base;\r\n' +
      '@tailwind components;\r\n' +
      '@tailwind utilities;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '@layer base {\r\n' +
      '  :root {\r\n' +
      '    --background: 0 0% 100%;\r\n' +
      '    --foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --muted: 210 40% 96.1%;\r\n' +
      '    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 46.9%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --popover: 0 0% 100%;\r\n' +
      '    --popover-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --border: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;\r\n' +
      '    --input: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --card: 0 0% 100%;\r\n' +
      '    --card-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --primary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '    --primary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --secondary: 210 40% 96.1%;\r\n' +
      '    --secondary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --accent: 210 40% 96.1%;\r\n' +
      '    --accent-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --destructive: 0 100% 50%;\r\n' +
      '    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --ring: 215 20.2% 65.1%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --radius: 0.5rem;\r\n' +
      '  }\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '  .dark {\r\n' +
      '    --background: 224 71% 4%;\r\n' +
      '    --foreground: 213 31% 91%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --muted: 223 47% 11%;\r\n' +
      '    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 56.9%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --accent: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
      '    --accent-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --popover: 224 71% 4%;\r\n' +
      '    --popover-foreground: 215 20.2% 65.1%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --border: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
      '    --input: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --card: 224 71% 4%;\r\n' +
      '    --card-foreground: 213 31% 91%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --primary: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
      '    --primary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 1.2%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --secondary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;\r\n' +
      '    --secondary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --destructive: 0 63% 31%;\r\n' +
      '    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --ring: 216 34% 17%;\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '    --radius: 0.5rem;\r\n' +
      '  }\r\n' +
      '}\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '@layer base {\r\n' +
      '  * {\r\n' +
      '    @apply border-border;\r\n' +
      '  }\r\n' +
      '  body {\r\n' +
      '    @apply bg-background text-foreground;\r\n' +
      '    font-feature-settings:\r\n' +
      '      "rlig" 1,\r\n' +
      '      "calt" 1;\r\n' +
      '  }\r\n' +
      '}\r\n',
    url: 'file:///C:/Users/aayus/Projects/e-commerce-platform/packages/ui/src/styles.css',
    file: 'C:\\Users\\aayus\\Projects\\e-commerce-platform\\packages\\ui\\src\\styles.css'
  },
  plugin: 'tailwindcss'
}
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

Here are my config files:
tailwind.config.ts
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
import sharedConfig from "@e-commerce-platform/tailwind-config";
import { fontFamily } from "tailwindcss/defaultTheme";
import tailwindcssAnimate from "tailwindcss-animate";

const config: Pick<
  Config,
  "prefix" | "presets" | "content" | "darkMode" | "theme" | "plugins"
> = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: ["./src/**/*.tsx"],
  prefix: "ui-",
  presets: [sharedConfig],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: `var(--radius)`,
        md: `calc(var(--radius) - 2px)`,
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-sans)", ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [tailwindcssAnimate],
};

export default config;


styles.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --muted: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 46.9%;

    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --border: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --input: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;

    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --primary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --primary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --secondary: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --secondary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --accent: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --accent-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --destructive: 0 100% 50%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --ring: 215 20.2% 65.1%;

    --radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: 224 71% 4%;
    --foreground: 213 31% 91%;

    --muted: 223 47% 11%;
    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 56.9%;

    --accent: 216 34% 17%;
    --accent-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --popover: 224 71% 4%;
    --popover-foreground: 215 20.2% 65.1%;

    --border: 216 34% 17%;
    --input: 216 34% 17%;

    --card: 224 71% 4%;
    --card-foreground: 213 31% 91%;

    --primary: 210 40% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 1.2%;

    --secondary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --secondary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --destructive: 0 63% 31%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --ring: 216 34% 17%;

    --radius: 0.5rem;
  }
}

@layer base {
  * {
    @apply border-border;
  }
  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
    font-feature-settings:
      "rlig" 1,
      "calt" 1;
  }
}



I would search your codebase for border-border and remove it. It's not a utility class that Tailwind provides and doesn't appear to be in your Tailwind config.

border-border is from shadcn

This seems similar to this issue
